# Prevent duplicate entry in Codeigniter

Tags: php, arrays, sql-server, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

How to prevent duplicate entry in codeigniter?
Following is the code:-

```
$params = array('value1' => 'test_value', 'value2' => 'test_value');
$this->db->insert('table_name',$params);
```

Comment: With a constraint in the database?

Comment: also in sql server triggers, how to prevent duplicacy?

Comment: With a constraint in the database?

Comment: @SeanLange any example?

Comment: Search for unique constraint. I couldn't possibly provide you an example, you haven't provided any details about your tables or what is considered a duplicate.

Comment: Okay. I will post with example.

Comment: Or you could just look at the documentation. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/create-unique-constraints

Comment: how come this question is related to sql-server? please use tags properly.

Comment: Please read documentations of the related framework when using them.  Have you created your database manually or using migrations of CodeIgniter?

Comment: @FLICKER can you check that i asked in comments that """also in sql server triggers, how to prevent duplicacy?""" Please read the whole conversation before commenting as I already had intention to ask in the context of SQL-server, also I am using SQL server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2 ways to prevent duplicate entry insertion into the database,

#### METHOD 1

You can use `$this->form_validation->set_rules` in the controller file and you can validate your input values,

*Example :*

#### In Controller

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('value1', 'value1 field label', 'trim|required|xss_clean|is_unique[table_name.value1]');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('value2', 'value2 field label', 'trim|required|xss_clean|is_unique[table_name.value2]');
$this->form_validation->set_message('is_unique', '%s is already exists');
if ($this->form_validation->run() === TRUE){
    // load your model function here
    $this->model_name->insert();
}
```

#### In Model

```
public function insert(){
    $postdata = $this->input->post();  
    extract($postdata);
    $this->db->insert('table_name', compact('value1','value2'));
    return ($this->db->trans_status()) ? $this->db->insert_id() : false;
}
```

#### METHOD 2

Validating values in model file before insert

```
$params = array('value1' => 'test_value', 'value2' => 'test_value');
extract($postdata);
if($this->db->limit(1)->get_where('table_name', compact('value1'))->num_rows() === 0 && $this->db->limit(1)->get_where('table_name', compact('value2'))->num_rows() === 0){
    $this->db->insert('table_name', $params);
}
return ($this->db->trans_status()) ? $this->db->insert_id() : false;
```

Answer (score -1):

model apply

function isVarExists($table,$var){ $query = $this->db ->select('*') ->where($var) ->get($table) ->num_rows(); return $query; }

controller

function validate_user_email(){ $uName['email'] = $this->input->post('email'); $isUNameCount = $this->User_model->isVarExists('user',$uName); if($isUNameCount > 0){ echo 'false'; } else{ echo 'true'; } }

Comment: Thanks for the effort but question was already answered. Good luck!